# How to keep PS1 when using nix-shell?

Tags: nixos, nix

`nix-shell` changes PS1 to its own format.

```
 [nix-shell:~/snm]$
```

I tried adding check for "$IN_NIX_SHELL" inside ~/.bashrc, but it didn't work.

The only work around I found is to run

```
nix-shell --run bash
```

Comment: What is the `PS1` that you want to keep, and where do you set it? Not knowing much about `nix-shell`, it seems obvious to me that if you run another shell, it may set its own prompt. You may want to look into how to configure the prompt for that shell.

Comment: my `PS1` in set in `~/.bashrc`, but nix-shell uses its own unless i explicitly tell it to run `bash`.

Comment: But having it run `bash` kinda defeats the purpose of running `nix-shell`, doesn't it? Why don't you just configure the prompt you want to use in the `nix-shell`? Or, alternatively, just use `bash`.  Note that I don't quite know what `nix-shell` is, but am assuming it's a shell like any other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Nix 2.4 [1] there is NIX_SHELL_PRESERVE_PROMPT environment variable which makes `nix-shell` preserve original `PS1`.
It can be added by

```
  home.sessionVariables = {
    NIX_SHELL_PRESERVE_PROMPT=1;
  };
```

1: https://discourse.nixos.org/t/nix-2-4-released/15822

Answer (score 1):

While `NIX_SHELL_PRESERVE_PROMPT` is the best option for Nix versions that support it, there exists a workaround for older versions which abuses the fact that while `nix-shell` sets its own `PS1` it does *not* set its own `PROMPT_COMMAND`. This lets you change `PS1` again *right before* the prompt is displayed (read: *after* `nix-shell` changes it) by making `PROMPT_COMMAND` set `PS1` (and then unset itself afterwards). For example, if you want a prompt that just says `>` , you could go

```bash
PROMPT_COMMAND='export PS1="> "; unset PROMPT_COMMAND'
```

to make `export PS1="> "` run once at a point when `nix-shell` should be done with that variable

Answer (score 0):

a wrapper script for `nix-shell`

based on the `PROMPT_COMMAND` solution by `Sara J`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# run nix-shell with a custom prompt string

# based on /etc/bashrc
# Provide a nice prompt if the terminal supports it.
if [ "$TERM" != "dumb" ] || [ -n "$INSIDE_EMACS" ]; then
  PROMPT_COLOR="1;31m"
  ((UID)) && PROMPT_COLOR="1;32m"
  if [ -n "$INSIDE_EMACS" ]; then
    # Emacs term mode doesn't support xterm title escape sequence (\e]0;)
    PS1="\n\[\033[$PROMPT_COLOR\][\u@\h:\w]\\$\[\033[0m\] "
  else
    PS1="\n\[\033[$PROMPT_COLOR\][\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\u@\h:\w]\\$\[\033[0m\] "
  fi
  if test "$TERM" = "xterm"; then
    PS1="\[\033]2;\h:\u:\w\007\]$PS1"
  fi
fi

# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/729431/295986
export PROMPT_COMMAND="export PS1=${PS1@Q}; unset PROMPT_COMMAND"

exec nix-shell "$@"
```